# How to execute command along with Rsync in linux

Tags: linux, rsync

I am looking forward to Rsync adhoc command to find a file in remote server and copy to localhost

Am approaching this way but its not working as expected

```
 rsync -avzP -e "'ssh -i mykey.ppk' 'admin@myserver.com' 'cd /home/profile/logs && ls -1 *.log | grep localhost | tail -1'" /tmp/
```

Comment: But why not 1. find file 2. then use rsync to copy it?

Comment: I've approached that way too by finding file and store in variable but its not working `log=$(ssh -i mykey.ppk' 'admin@myserver.com' 'cd /home/profile/logs && ls -1 *.log | grep localhost | tail -1')` `rsync -avzP -vvv $log /tmp/` its looking for the log value in current server path, obviously its on remote server

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.